# Refresh panelGrid whenever gets updated

Tags: css, jsf, .refresh

how to refresh the JSF panelgrid whenever data gets updated in db without refreshing the whole page.is there anything can be configured? or i should created a backbean function ? can anyone guide me with a example?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way is to do so using *Push Technology* (You can trigger client behavior from the server)

For example *PrimePush* by Primefaces : [PrimePush](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/push/index.jsf) , but its not perfect yet , supposed to be in 3.5 version (I think)

So for now you can use [Primefaces Poll](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/poll.jsf) , that way you will check every X seconds if the data was changed and if so, you could update a particular element using the `update` attribute